# Trying to make the boxes in this last row appear

Tags: html, css

New to this and trying to make the attached layout. [Box Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qjmF.png)

I can't seem to get the last row of 4 boxes in the middle section to appear. Once I do I will adjust all the surrounding widths and heights to make it nice and clean. I looked on line and it seems like I have cleared everything properly and I don't think it has to do with the "boxstyle" class being applied incorrectly as I played with that using google dev tools already. Any help you can provide would be amazing.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Layout Challenge</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Layout Challenge"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="layout, challenge, classwork"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Chantel Zapata"/>
</head>

<body>

<header class="marketnavrow1">
    <div class="marketnavrow1a boxstyle">
    </div> 
    <nav class="marketnavrow1b">
        <ul>
            <li class="boxstyle"></li>
            <li class="boxstyle"></li>
            <li class="boxstyle"></li>
            <li class="boxstyle"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="magazine">
    <aside class="boxstyle"></aside>
    <div class="secondary">
        <div class="mag1strowbox boxstyle">
        </div>
        <div class="mag2ndrowbox">
            <div class="mag2ndrowbox1 boxstyle">
            </div>
            <div class="mag2ndrowbox2 boxstyle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mag3rdrowbox">
                <div class="4colrow boxstyle"></div>
                <div class="4colrow boxstyle"></div>
                <div class="4colrow boxstyle"></div>
                <div class="4colrow last"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1090px;
    }
.indextext {
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-family: "Arial", Verdana, san serif;
}
.boxstyle {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #969696;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
    }
.tcbox1 {
  height: 164px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  clear: both;
  width: 1090px;
}
.tcbox2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.tcbox2a {
  height: 450px;
  width: 735px; 
  float: left;
}
.tcbox2b {
  height: 450px;
  width: 335px;
  float: right;
}
.tcbox3 {
  clear: both;
  height: 164px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 1090px;
}
.threecbox2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.threecbox2a {
  height: 450px;
  width: 206px;
  float: left;
}
.threecbox2b {
  height: 450px;
  width: 638px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.threecbox2c {
  height: 450px;
  width: 206px;
  float: right;
}
.smpmrketrow2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.smpmrketrow2a {
    height: 450px;
    width: 535px;
    float: left;
}
.smpmrketrow2b {
    height: 450px;
    width: 535px;
    float: right;
}
.smpmrketrow3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.smpmrketrow3a {
    height: 220px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
}
.smpmrketrow3b {
    height: 220px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.smpmrketrow3c {
    height: 220px;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
}
.marketnavrow1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.marketnavrow1a {
    height: 124px;
    width: 264px;
    float: left;
}
.marketnavrow1b { 
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
}
header nav { 
    height: 90px;
    width: 704px;
    float: right;
}
header nav ul { 
    list-style: none; 
}
header nav ul li {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.marketnavrow2 {
    height: 450px;
    width: 1090px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
.magazine {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
aside {
    height: 240px;
    width: 264px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.secondary {
    float: right;
}
.mag1strowbox {
  width: 480px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mag2ndrowbox {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mag2ndrowbox .mag2ndrowbox1 {
  float: left;
  width: 355px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.mag2ndrowbox .mag2ndrowbox2 {
  float: left;
  width: 105px;
  height: 200px;
}
.mag3rdrowbox {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.mag3rdrowbox .4colrow {
  float: left;
  width: 105px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.mag3rdrowbox .4colrow .last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class `.4colrow` to something that doesn't start with a number.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcn1z16j/1/)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Just so I know for future use, does this mean that I should never start a class with a number?

Comment: Yes that is correct. As a general rule of thumb only use letters, numbers, hyphens (`-`), and underscores (`_`) and only start them with a letter.